# Best way to load SQL Server table records from the Database and send them via a WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Mainly I need to move database tables from one machine to another.

**IMPORTANT:** the server is ONLY accessible via WCF, so I cannot use SQL Server Mirroring or other direct SQL Server techniques.

I need to load an entire table on the client and prepare it so that I can send it via WCF in an optimized way.

The client (and server) are based on C# and I could use any technique available on the client (EF4, Linq2SQL ...) to load and prepare the data.

On the server, I also use C# but I can only receive the table rows via a WCF.

Once again, I can only access the server via WCF so no other options are available at this time.

**QUESTIONS:**
1) So what would be the best way to load those tables into the client and prepare them for the WCF call?

2) And more importantly, what would the WCF params to pass the table records ..look like??

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like something better solved with ADO.NET, rather than trying to use Entity Framework.

Comment: How many records are in these tables?

Comment: Possibly 1000's the first time around and then ...since it's a scheduled client, just the delta from last upload.

By ADO.NET means a straight DataReader, right? and in what format shall i send the tables thru the WCF?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use any database techniques, probably the optimal option is to do it in chunks by using linq's TAKE and SKIP arguments with the Entity Framework.

But in reality if there was a requirement to copy tables, I would seriously look at using the database tools (For Sql Server - BCP) and move the data out to a file and then in to a staging table on the other server.  Then use MERGE to move the data from staging to production.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter to much really how you get the data from the DB - use whatever is fast and lightweight, say a precompiled Linq to SQL query or regular ADO.Net.

(**EDIT:** Or dump it out to a file as mentioned by @John Raynor)

If you have very large amounts of data to move then I would first of all consider streaming rather than standard WCF buffering (maybe only for the initial transfer - depends on the size of data). This will avoid too much resource usage on the client and server since they will not have to buffer all the data in one go.

The is a good guide on streaming with WCF here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

If firewalls are not an issue you should use TCP instead of HTTP as it is more compact.

Another thing to consider is the type of encoding to use. Since you control both sides of the system (client and server) you could go for a binary encoding. The standard .Net one is OK, but if you can spend some money, I have found the Fast Infoset encoding from noemax to be excellent.

http://www.noemax.com/products/fastinfoset/index.html

Comment: Very helpful answers ...thanks. so finally, the WCF call should have as a param what type (for a table named Users) for example ?

Comment: It would be of type Stream. The idea is that you serialise the result set, in whatever for it is into a stream and send that. I think the best approach for large data would be to dump it into a file and stream that, so you would extract the data to a file and then open a FileStream to the file and return that.

Comment: Just for me to be sure i understand ..let's say we are using Linq2SQL, is there a special way to create that file and convert it into a stream ?

Comment: Well, as per my edit, I would use the BCP method recommended by John Raynor, rather than L2SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Well EF is Microsoft's recommened data access method.  You could use linq to entities to query against ef with no condition and return that in your WCF method.  Though I do have to say that, and this is a bit obvious, the more records your table have the slower your WCF service will run since all data must be serialized.

Here is a link that may help you to get started with EF and WCF together

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336128.aspx

Comment: Also is this only for purposes of migrating data from one server to another and not for accessing by user groups.  If so could you use database mirroring or someother technology.  I know you mentioned that there is only access via web services but I thought I would at least see.

Comment: right...so my only connection between clients and server is via WCF. So for EF loading, you suggest to pass the var xx.ToArray() as param to the WCF call ?

Comment: -1: bad idea to return EF entities. They will include implementation-specific data, like the base classes.

Comment: Well with EF you can use Code First and create POCO classes. When you do this there really is no difference between what you suggested and what I did. Plus it sounds like this is to be executed strictly inside her network so as long as its not passing connection string information what does it matter?  I fail to see why returning EF entities in a WCF service is bad.  This is a fundemental requirement in web development. Also if it was bad why would they make RIA services that are designed to return only entities?

Answer (score -1):

WCF can serialize a `System.Data.DataTable`. You could basically:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITableReader
{
  [OperationContract]
  DataTable GetTable();
}
```

And read the whole table into a `DataTable` with ADO.NET.

If the tables are really big, you could split it up into multiple cals to get chunks of the table, but WCF would have no problems sending back a couple dozen megs if needed. You would just have to up the message sizes on the binding config.

Comment: -1: yeah, it _can_ do this, but _should not_. Why make this contract platform specific if you don't have to? And is there some performance benefit to using `DataTable` over something less platform specific like `List<RecordType>`?

Comment: @John Saunders : I haven't used EF4 so maybe this has changed, but I was under the impression that EF entities (in EF1 anyway) aren't WCF serializable by default. I was just proposing a dead simple no-frills solution.

Comment: EF entities were always serializable, and I wouldn't use those, either.

Comment: @JohnSaunders By RecordType you suggest what exactly (to be more specific)

Comment: @Developer: I recommend creating "data transfer object" classes with  properties that match the columns you want to return. Return a List of those objects, populated from the database, using whatever data access technique you like. That gives you full control over what the service returns, with no platform-specific or implementation-specific types being transferred.